# Eliminating repetition in similar scripts

Tags: javascript

I have a series of webpages with prices that change rapidly and due to a certain constraint, I need all the pages to query a certain XML file that is dynamically updated.

This is what I have cobbled together, and though it works fine, I'm sure I'm overdoing it and adding a full script for every price line is clunky at best.

```
<h4> <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","flightprice.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("EACH2PAX1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(" per person / Duration: 30 minutes, 2 passenger minimum. ");
  } 
</script></h4>


<h4> <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","flightprice.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("EACH3PAX1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(" per person with passengers");
  } 
</script></h4>
```

Since each script is a IDENTICAL, except for the document.write value in each, I was hoping for a cleaner way of doing this.

Please excuse my ignorance... I'm 13 years old and trying to learn with the tools available to me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nice job Farhat. What you need is an introduction to [procedural programming principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming).

You group your common code into a single function. Since you create the XMLHttp object twice, you could put it into a function

```
function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Then you could call it in your code like this:

```
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
xmlhttp.open("GET","flightprice.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
...
```

That is just a start. There are more places you can make your code more modular. The process is known as refactoring.

Comment: To be honest, there's no need for `ActiveXObject` anyway. IE6? Nah. Not worth it.

Comment: @Neit Well, we're still at the Hello World phase, didn't want to get into async calls, OOP, etc. lol

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help Gordon.  I am taking programming classes in school now and trying to learn all I can.  Everyone here is so nice and helpful, but sometimes they make me feel dumb.     You are so helpful.